# Нету доступа к phpmyadmin

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, apache2

Заказчик дал виртуальную машину на ubuntu 14.04, где был их сайт. После того как снесли их сайт и поставили вместо него fork-cms. Обновив php5 на php7.1, то phpmeadmin исчез, а ставиться заново он не хочет. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Найдите знающего сисадмина(локально)

Comment: @Arsen, не вариант

Comment: Давайте найдем шамана, только он  сможет рассказать каковы ошибки при установки phpMyadmin  или вы сами может напишете ?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вы ставите phpmyadmin через apt-get install phpmyadmin. Попробуйте просто скачать исходники и положить их туда где они должны лежать по конфигу апача или nginx.